# Command line switch for Word that will set the SaveAs Path

Tags: command-line, office-2007

I am looking for the switch that will set the default SaveAs path for a word document when calling it from the command line. It [seems](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HA101580301033.aspx) like the /p parameter exists for Excel but I haven't found any similar switch for WinWord. Does it exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the switch you desire [exists](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210565)